# nodejs server hub for telegram

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

Let's say I want to run multiple telegram bots in the same server. I'd need a kind of hub to send the requests to the right bots, but I don't want to modify the bot's code, I just want to send the request to it. Since NodeJS is single threaded, how do I do it? How can I keep the bots running and send them requests, make them process it and send the requests back to the client?

I thought of using require, but how does require works? Will it simply include the entire code? Will it be executing in some area?

I've read that only i/o processes are executed asynchronously, so whenever the hub receives a data and passes it to the module (which is a bot), this will not execute asynchronously, right?

Comment: What have you tried? The entire point of node.js is that the only way to do anything is to do it the right way. The creator of node.js chose a language that did not have blocking calls so that it was possible to write anything synchronously. As long as there are no global variables, then you just have to instantiate a new bot. There CAN'T be threading issues.

Comment: @Aron can I just requite the bot code and use it so?

Comment: Depends. If the bot was well made, you require it, and new up an instance. If not, then you are stuffed.

Comment: @aron sorry, didn't understand, I require it and pass data to it, no?